# making windows 8 partition larger

Tags: partitioning, live-cd, gparted

My diskimage is here:

[image]

My problem is that I want to make my windows 8 partition larger. More specifically I want to use my Restore partition to enlarge my windows partition by 20GB.I think that restore partition was put there when windows 8 was installed.  What is the best solution here? Is this possible with Gparted and a live cd?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to remove the recovery partition? It will make recovering a dead windows installation much more difficult.

From a LiveCD with GParted, you can delete that partition (`sda6`), move all partitions after your Windows partition (`sda4` in this instance) towards the end of the disk¹, and resize `sda4`.

¹ This can take *hours*.